# Recursive function keeps returning false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a little trouble why my recursive function keeps returning back false.

```
const location = {
   name: "917",
   parentLocationCluster: {
     name: "Key Zones"
      ParentLocationCluster: {
        name: "Bla"
     }
   }
}

const test = CheckIfInKeyZone(location)

const CheckIfInKeyZone = (parentLocationCluster) => {
  if(parentLocationCluster.name === 'Key Zones') {
    return true;
  }
  else if(parentLocationCluster.parentLocationCluster) {
    const { parentLocationCluster: location } = parentLocationCluster;
    CheckIfInKeyZone(location);
  }
  return false;
};
```

The `parentLocationCluster.name === 'Key Zones'`  is hit, in which i expect the return value to be true, however, it isnt.

help?

Comment: When you make a recursive call, you don't `return` the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor mistake it should be:

> return CheckIfInKeyZone(location);

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return` to the recursive call.

```
const CheckIfInKeyZone = (parentLocationCluster) => {
  if(parentLocationCluster.name === 'Key Zones') {
    return true;
  }
  else if(parentLocationCluster.parentLocationCluster) {
    const { parentLocationCluster: location } = parentLocationCluster;
    // added return
    return CheckIfInKeyZone(location);
  }
  return false;
};
```

If you don't add that `return`, it will call `CheckIfInKeyZone`, but won't get the return value of that.

Answer (score 0):

As per Pointys response, missing `return` from the result

```
const location = {
   name: "917",
   parentLocationCluster: {
     name: "Key Zones"
      ParentLocationCluster: {
        name: "Bla"
     }
   }
}

const test = CheckIfInKeyZone(location)

const CheckIfInKeyZone = (parentLocationCluster) => {
  if(parentLocationCluster.name === 'Key Zones') {
    return true;
  }
  else if(parentLocationCluster.parentLocationCluster) {
    const { parentLocationCluster: location } = parentLocationCluster;
    return CheckIfInKeyZone(location);
  }
  return false;
};
```